# C#, YouTube Data API, CommentThreads.List(), insufficient authentication scopes when using OAuth

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

If I use the API key method (the `RunAPIKey()` method below), it succeeds. But If I use OAuth method (`RunOauth()` below), it fails with the following exception:

```
Error: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

Why is it so? Of course, I had allowed it with my YouTube account when the browser opened the OAuth page. I found a similar question, but the answer, adding the "force SSL" scope, did not work. Setting the `req.Key` with the API key did not work, either. I used [the official sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

namespace APITest
{
    internal class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API");
            Console.WriteLine("========================");

            try
            {
                //new Test().RunAPIKey().Wait(); //Works.
                new Test().RunOauth().Wait(); //Doesn't work.
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task RunAPIKey()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "apparently_I_cant_show_this",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var req = youtubeService.CommentThreads.List("snippet");
            req.VideoId = "NK7iIBcsBn4";
            req.MaxResults = 5;

            var res = await req.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var item in res.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.TextDisplay);
            }
        }

        private async Task RunOauth()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
                    // authenticated user's account.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var req = youtubeService.CommentThreads.List("snippet");
            req.VideoId = "NK7iIBcsBn4";
            req.MaxResults = 5;

            var res = await req.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var item in res.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.TextDisplay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed adding the `YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl` scope. This is stupid, because [Google's documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) does not mention that it requires `YoutubeForceSsl`, unlike the `insert` API where [it mentions that the `insert` API requires `YoutubeForceSsl`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert).

But just adding it after already having gotten the authentication did not work. It must get the authentication again to apply the changed scope. Since I did not know how to do that, I opened another [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940262/how-to-forget-already-given-oauth-and-ask-for-it-again).